# Approximate dirac delta and integration error

Tags: distribution-theory

For a sequence of functions $g_n(x-x_o)$ approximating the Dirac delta I can write:

$ \int_a^b g_n(x-x_o) f(x) dx = \int_a^b \delta(x-x_o) f(x) dx + \epsilon_n$

when $x_o \in [a,b]$. I am trying to estimate the error term $\epsilon_n$ when $g_n(x-x_o)$ is a Gaussian function. Does anybody know how this might be done?

PS: I have seen calculations of upper bounds for $\epsilon_n$ when $g_n$ is a Gaussian. But these upper bound calculations are more concerned with the dependence of the error upon $n$ (which is inversely proportional to the width of the Gaussian) than a reasonable estimate of $\epsilon_n$. If I try using the error term given by these upper bounds calculations to estimate the error then the error is far larger than what one might expect.

Comment: What kind of a function is $f$?

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't really gain a lot by restricting to the interval $[a,b]$ unless $f$ is a very quickly growing function.  If it is, then since you are already cutting it off, you might as well do so smoothly and work on $(-\infty,\infty)$.  With a bit of regularity (two derivatives and some growth conditions on the first derivative), you can actually write down a non-trivial exact expression for that error using Ito's lemma.  If you want non-trivial uniform control on this type of error, you are going to need some regularity assumptions on the second derivative.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to represent my real problem accurately and therefore I set finite limits on the integral. Can you link me to Ito's lemma?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D%27s_lemma  

It still matters what kind of function $f$ is.  For example, for $f$ growing at a sufficiently large exponential rate as $x \to b$, the integral on the left is infinite.  I only use that as an example.  If all you know is that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then you aren't going to do much better than what you get with uniform continuity, a Gaussian tail bound and bounding $f$ by its supremum norm.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I should probably add that $f$ is compactly supported on $[a,b]$.